# python sort tuple by different criteria

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I have a list `a = [(1,'a'), (1,'b'), (2,'c')]`, and I want to get this list: `[(2,'c'), (1,'a'), (1,'b')]`

If I do this:

```
sorted(a, reverse=True)
```

I can only get:

```
[(2,'c'), (1,'b'), (1,'a')]
```

How can I get the list I want?

Comment: you mean you want preserve the order of the existing, already sorted elements?

Comment: If the OP wants to preserve second element order, I disagree this is a duplicate.

Comment: Preserve second element order? OP will have to clarify that is what they want - at this point it looks to me they want to sort by decreasing number value and then by increasing alphabetical order.

Comment: Do `sorted(a, key=lambda x: (-x[0], x[1]))`. It will return you with: `[(2, 'c'), (1, 'a'), (1, 'b')]`

Comment: OP: there are 2 possible questions asked here: either "preserve the ordering of elements with equal item 0", or "sort the items (descending on the first element, ascending on the second)". Which one do you want?

Comment: Sorry I did not make my question clear. This is what I want: sort the first element of the tuple descendingly and if the first element is the same, sort the second element ascendingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve the sort order in the original list, but sort only by the first element, you can do

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> a = [(1,'a'), (1, 'x'), (1,'b'), (2,'c')]
>>> sorted(a, key=itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
[(2, 'c'), (1, 'a'), (1, 'x'), (1, 'b')]
```

In Python the `sort` and `sorted` functions use the [TimSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) algorithm, which is a stable sort. Being stable means that the original relative ordering is preserved for those elements that compare equal to each other.

If you want to sort by multiple criteria *at the same time*, you can use a function for the key in case of integers, returning the opposite number of the number for reversing, but in general case you could do so by sorting several times, in reverse order:

```
>>> b = sorted(a, key=itemgetter(1))        # sort by second element, ascending
>>> b.sort(key=itemgetter(0), reverse=True) # sort by first element, descending
>>> b
[(2, 'c'), (1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'x')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve this by using `lambda` function with `sorted`:

```
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x: (-x[0], x[1]))
[(2, 'c'), (1, 'a'), (1, 'b')]
```

This will sort the list in descending order of the value at index 0, and then ascending order of value at index 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(a, key=itemgetter(0),reverse=True)
```

**Result**

```
[(2, 'c'), (1, 'a'), (1, 'b')]
```